# generate random decimal numbers from 0 to 1 with normal distribution using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I am new to numpy. I want to generate random values from 0 to 1 with random distribution using numpy, the known input is the standard deviation = 0.2 and the Mean = 0.55 and no. of population = 1000. I used this code:

```
number = np.random.normal(avg, std_dev, num_pop).round(2)
```

However it generated number with negative values and also values greater than 1. How to limit the value from 0 to 1?

Comment: The normal distribution is not bounded. What you're looking for is impossible.
you can use instead another distribution that's called a [truncated normal distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html). the scipy library has an implementation of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal distribution has no lower or upper bound, and sampling from it and discarding the results outside your bounds until you get the 1000 necessary points would be awkward.
Luckily there's the truncated normal distribution:

```
from scipy import stats

low = 0
high = 1
mean = 0.55
stddev = 0.2
num_pop = 1000

number = stats.truncnorm.rvs(low, high,
                             loc = mean, scale = stddev,
                             size = num_pop)
```

Comment: I know `from scipy import stats` but OP want using `numpy`

Comment: OP : `I want to generate random values from 0 to 1 with random distribution using numpy,`

Comment: Fair point, but it's also fair to point out that SciPy is the library where they put all the features while NumPy was branched off as the bare minimum array module (NumPy was even tentatively called SciPy Core). There could very well be good reasons to use NumPy without SciPy, but that's intentionally sacrificing features.

Comment: SciPy outputs NumPy arrays, so you can apply all your NumPy knowledge to SciPy code.

Comment: I see, it seems that scipy can solve my problem!

Comment: Think of NumPy as a gas tank and SciPy as a car. Their main product is the car including the gas tank, but they also sell the gas tank alone for people who only need a small part for their own machines.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Here's what I used to resolve it:

```py
number = abs(np.random.normal(0,1,1))
if number > 1:
    number = number - 1
```

`abs` finds the absolute value of `number`, making it positive.

The if statement at the end makes sure the number does not go over one, because we are using a normal distribution which does not have an upper or lower limit.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
number = numpy.random.rand(1).round(2)
```

It will generate a random number in interval [0,1).

Comment: is this produce normal distribution?

Comment: @user1740577, no. this produces samples from a uniformly distributed random variable.

Comment: @yannziselman exactly I ask this question that Rahul know that his answer is wrong

Comment: Yes it will produce results from uniform distribution. OP needs values between 0-1. 
You can substract mean from value you get and multiply it with standard deviation. Hope im correct on this one